# Rollover button doesn't appear in sidebar

Tags: css, html, widget-text

For some reason, I can't add a PayPal donate button to the sidebar of my website. I've been using CSS to create a rollover effect, and while it's worked on a static page of my site: http://kellygreenproject.com/volunteer-2, the same method doesn't appear to work in the top widget on the right sidebar of the site.

#### CSS:

```
a.paypalButton {
    display: block;
    width: 207px;
    height: 44px;
    background-image: url('http://kellygreenproject.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/General-Donate.png');
}

a.paypalButton:hover {
    background-position: bottom left;
}
```

#### HTML:

```
<a class="paypalButton" href="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=YJFFMF5R5TJ9J"> </a>
```

I even added the button to the bottom of the volunteer page (http://kellygreenproject.com/volunteer-2) and it works there, but just doesn't show up in the sidebar. If I write text between the a tag it places the button as a background, but that's definitely not what I want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution for your problem

1.This css code conflict with your css ( for paypal button )

```
#widgets .textwidget a {
display: inline;
}

and

#widgets a {
display: inline-block;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

2.put !important in display property

```
a.paypalButton {
        display: block!important;
        width: 207px;
        height: 44px;
        background-image: url('http://kellygreenproject.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/General-Donate.png');
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much Ravs! I'm assuming the !important declaration overrides the widget CSS? It works great.